# react-native-datepicker not showing numbers for time select in selector

Tags: react-native, datepicker

I am using react-native-datepicker library.On my emulator is working all fine.When I click to select time value for From and Until it opens a selector and the numbers in slider for select are black collor.But when I open on real device and click to select time for those values (From and Until) it opens selector but the numbers as well as AM/PM text are not visible.They are present, because I can blindly select some value, but I cannot see the numbers.Like they are also white.

So only values which present format is not visible.Cancel and Confirm Buttons are black and they are visible, but numbers for select and PM/AM are not visible.Once again they are present because I can slide and select blindly some value.
This is my code

```
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';

<DatePicker
                        style={{marginBottom:20}}
                        value={selectedTimeFrom}
                        mode="time"
                        is24Hour={false}
                        date={selectedTimeFrom}
                        
                        display="spinner"
                        format="h:mm A" 
                        confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                        cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                      
                        onDateChange={(time) => setSelectedTimeFrom(time)}
                        showIcon={false}
                        customStyles={{
                          dateInput: {
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderRadius:8,
                            marginTop:10,
                            alignItems: 'flex-start', 
                            color:'blue',
                            backgroundColor:'#fff',
                          },
                          dateText: {
                            fontSize:dynamicFontSize(3.5),
                            color: '#000',
                            alignSelf:'center',
                          },
                          btnTextConfirm: {
                            color: '#5ce1e6',
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                          },
                          btnTextCancel: {
                            color: 'black', 
                          },
                          textStyle: {
                            color: 'black', 
                          },
                         
                        }}
                      >
                      
                      </DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check If you are using DARK Mode in your mobile

Comment: Wow you were right, when i changed to light mode it was all good.But how can i create to be visible regardless of the Mobile theme settings.It should be always visible